# Is my azure portal connected to the right LUIS.ai app?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

How can I make sure that the bot I am training in LUIS.ai is connected to the bot service I am using in my Azure Portal. Although I have multiple intents. It shows only intent None which makes me think they are not connected. Can I still connect it or do I need to start over? Thanks for the help

Comment: Check that the ApplicationId is correct.

Comment: can you please post your dialog class code so we can take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things that could be wrong here:

1. Have you trained/published your model?
2. Do you have the following attribute on your dialog class? `[LuisModel("YOUR LUIS APP ID", "YOUR BOOTSTRAP/API KEY")]` (assuming you are using C#)

Comment: This worked thank you. I needed to publish my bot before testing in the emulator.